# College grads earning more than a high school grad metric: Entry and Exit Cohort criteria

Tags: collegescorecard

For the College Scorecard metric used by 2024 USNWR "College grads earning more than a high school grad" or the Entry Cohorts and Exit Cohorts, are the cohorts determined by semester, by academic year, or by calendar year?